# Как вставить примечание с текстом из соседней ячейки

Tags: excel, vba

Есть 2 столбца **A** и **B**, как можно добавить во все ячейки **B** примечание с текстом из **A**. В каждой строчке свой текст.

Вручную будет долго, формула в примечание вставляется как текст

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub AddComments()
Dim oneCell As Range
For Each oneCell In Range("B1:B5")
    If oneCell.Comment Is Nothing Then oneCell.AddComment
    oneCell.Comment.Text oneCell.Offset(0, -1).Text
Next
End Sub
```

> ничего не подскажу, кроме общего соображения: опишите, что именно предлагаете. – aleksandr barakin

Перебираем все ячейки нужного диапазона по одной. Сперва проверяем, есть ли у очередной ячейки комментарий (в смысле место под него), если нет - добавляем. Потом записываем в комментарий нужный текст. Текст берём из соседней ячейки - задаём смещение от текущей на 1 ячейку влево.

Comment: Благодарю, очень элегантное решение! :)

Comment: тут такая дилемма получается: тот, кому понятен код без объяснений, не нуждается в этом ответе (он ведь и сам, скорее всего, сможет написать этот код). а тот, кому этот ответ действительно нужен (это ведь не только автор данного вопроса), с большой вероятностью, не поймёт его без пояснений. как разрешить дилемму? наиболее очевидный путь: добавить пояснения к коду.

Comment: ну, если даже специалист не понимает, какое описание можно дать коду, то такой дилетант как я вообще в пролёте. так что ничего не подскажу, кроме общего соображения: опишите, что именно предлагаете.

Comment: не знаю, мне сложно судить — я в этой проприетарщине совсем не силён. вообще мне очень нравится такая распространённая приписываемая разным персонажам максима: «если вы не можете объяснить это своей бабушке, вы сами этого не понимаете».

Comment: вот что ещё могу добавить: стоит ориентироваться на признанные хорошими ответы: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aa

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin *вообще мне очень нравится такая распространённая приписываемая разным персонажам максима: «если вы не можете объяснить это своей бабушке, вы сами этого не понимаете».* Не забывайте - она предполагает. что "своя бабушка" активно участвует в процессе, или по крайней мере говорит, что именно она не поняла.

Comment: не-не-не, данный вопрос может возникнуть у «совсем зелёных бабушек». и вот они полезут в интернеты искать ответа на вопрос. и найдут вот этот ваш ответ. поймут они то, что вы предлагаете?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin У меня есть несколько ответов, где были заданы дополнительные вопросы, и ответы дополнены блоками объяснений. Причём есть и ответы, где дополнительные вопросы заданы другими участниками, не автором. Это ведь не так сложно - спросить. А если кто-то не хочет спросить - да нужны ли ему вообще объяснения?

Comment: а вы не забывайте о том, что для того, чтобы спросить (написать комментарий к произвольному сообщению) надо как минимум зарегистрироваться и набрать 50 баллов репутации. так что надо как-то золотую середину находить (объяснять, где находится эникей, который надо пресс — это противоположная крайность).

Comment: @Akina, я бы добавил проверку на наличие значения (кому нужны пустые примечания?). Например: `If oneCell.Offset(0, -1).Value <> "" Then`

Comment: @vikttur Тогда, если продолжать эту логику, надо проверять наличие комментария и, если он есть, но ячейка пуста, удалять? Я думаю, что всё это как-то немного выходит за рамки вопроса.

Comment: @Akina, и не просто удалять, а изменять все комментарии, ведь значение могло поменяться :) Но согласен - это для универсальности, не прямо по вопросу

Comment: @vikttur Линейный алгоритм получается такой: а) если нет комментария - вставить его; б) если поле пустое - удалить комментарий. Ну или ветвить - вложенные IF. Просто по-моему, добавление этих украшений не должно вызвать сложности, если понять, что и как делает приведённый код.